# Rearranging data for multi line headers in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, pivot, melt

I am working with the following data from FWI in pandas

[image]
I want to transform it to following form for each country
[image]

I have tried using the melt, stack, and pivot function but have not been able to achieve desired result with these multi line headers. Link for the dataset: https://freedomhouse.org/sites/default/files/2021-02/Country_and_Territory_Ratings_and_Statuses_FIW1973-2021.xlsx
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the column headers as a `MultiIndex`, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) the columns (`unstack` works on the row index, so you have to transpose the dataframe).

```
df = pd.read_excel('Country_and_Territory_Ratings_and_Statuses_FIW1973-2021.xlsx', 'Territory Ratings, Statuses',skiprows=1, header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

The issue with this particular Excel table is that there is a trailing space after some `'CL'` header names (i.e. they are `'CL'` and `'CL '`). You can fix this by re-creating the index like so:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.get_level_values(0),
                                        df.columns.get_level_values(1).str.strip()])
```

Then unstack:

```
result = df.T.unstack(0).T
```